# Fail to authenticate Gsuit user using OAUTh2

Tags: c#, google-oauth

I am getting exception randomly while authenticating Google user by OAUTH2. I have generated the token for the user first time authentication. But after some time randomly application throwing following error

[image]

**EDIT:** Exception occurs on subsequent launch of the application.

Comment: It is something like the authentication failure from Google side. Are you using correct credentials?

Comment: Yes. Credentials are correct. Its authenticated properly for and token is also generated during first few attempts. It starts throwing error randomly.